# Rename Columns of Data.frame in list

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I am trying to use lapply (and want the solution with lapply) to rename columns of a data.frame located in a list, but it's returning names, not the renamed data.frames:

```
# define list
li <- list(u_n = data.frame(x = 1:3), r_l = data.frame(y = 4:6))

# trying to rename columns after the element of the list they're located in
li_2 <- lapply(1:length(li),
                function(x,y) colnames(y[[x]]) <- names(y)[x], y = li)
```

However, this returns:

```
[[1]]
[1] "u_n"

[[2]]
[1] "r_l"
```

If I use the same method as the function specified in lapply individually, it does work:

```
li[1]
$u_n
  x
1 1
2 2
3 3

colnames(li[[1]]) <- names(li)[1]

li[1]
$u_n
  u_n
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We may need to return the object after naming it.

```
 li_2 <- lapply(seq_along(li), function(i) {
               colnames(li[[i]]) <- names(li)[i]
               li[[i]]})
```

Or this can be done with `setNames`

```
 li_2 <- lapply(names(li), function(x) setNames(li[[x]], x) )
```

Or we could use `Map`, which is a wrapper for `mapply` (that is a multivariate version of `sapply`).  We apply the `FUN` to corresponding elements of each input.

```
 li_2 <- Map(setNames, li, names(li))
```

Here, we are changing the column names of each `list` element with corresponding names of the `list` element.  If we are using anonymous function, it would be

```
 Map(function(x,y) setNames(x,y), li, names(li))
```

Comment: This is amazing feedback @akrun ! I appreciate all the solutions, it really helps me learn the language.

Comment: @RyanErwin  Glad to know that it helps.  Thanks for the reply.