# How to merge multiple excel sheets (of varying length) into a dataframe according to ID number?

Tags: r, excel, vba

I have an Excel document with multiple sheets, on each sheet the first column contains sample IDs. Each sheet then has multiple columns with different measures.

I am trying to join all these sheets together with R to make a data frame but as not every sample is in each sheet, I'm having trouble making a dataframe. I have tried this:

```
library(readxl)
read_excel_allsheets <- function(filename) {
    sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
    x <- lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = X))
    names(x) <- sheets
    x
}
# to join up multiple sheets
testsheets <- read_excel_allsheets("test.xlsx")
as.data.frame(testsheets) #not possible different lengths?
```

Is there a way to fill in the missing points with Nas, and then join everything? How do I make sure the sheets are joined according to ID number, so I don't get a separate ID number column for each sheet?

Comment: Try `Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x, y, by="ID", all=T), testsheets)`

Comment: Thanks!  but I get an error: 
      Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column
I think this is because when i join them using read_excel_allsheets it creates a bunch of columns with the same name...

Comment: Yes, there must be a uniquely valid column in each dataframe. Try to rename the ID column. See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540530/rename-columns-of-data-frame-in-list