# rename columns in a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, lapply

I need to be able to rename columns by name in a list of dataframes that can all expected to have the same names.

For example:

```
[[1]]
  col1 col2
1    1    2
2    2    3

[[2]]
  col1 col2
1    1    2
2    2    3
```

Should become:

```
[[1]]
  ID col2
1    1    2
2    2    3

[[2]]
  ID col2
1    1    2
2    2    3
```

data:

```
col1 <- c(1,2)
col2 <- c(2,3)
myList <- list(data.frame(col1,col2),data.frame(col1,col2))
```

my attempt:

```
lapply(myList, function(x){
  names(myList[[x]])[names(myList[[x]]) =="col1"] <- "ID"
})
```

Where did I go wrong? I need base R.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to refer to names(x)[1] by name not index.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read that: `lapply(myList, function(x) {names(x)[which(names(x) == "col1")] <- "ID"; x})` Note the `; x` - its important that your function returns `x`

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename Columns of Data.frame in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540530/rename-columns-of-data-frame-in-list)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `{dplyr}` and `{purrr}` from the `{tidyverse}`

```
> library(purrr)
> library(dplyr)
> 
> df1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:2, col2 = 3:4)
> df2 <- data.frame(col1 = 3:2, col2 = 6:7)
> 
> list(df1, df2) %>% map(~ rename(., ID = col1))
[[1]]
  ID col2
1  1    3
2  2    4

[[2]]
  ID col2
1  3    6
2  2    7
```

It also works with strings: `list(df1, df2) %>% map(~ rename(., "ID" = "col1"))`

Comment: You might want to post this answer on the duplicate question, since it doesn't have a tidyverse answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540530/rename-columns-of-data-frame-in-list